# How can i send intent from firebase push?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need send link from firebase notification than my webView loading this link.

How can i resolve it? Maybe i can check it on the service, if yes, so how?

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String msg = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String channel = remoteMessage.getNotification().getChannelId();
        Log.d("edc", "" + msg);


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way or not but you can send your link in the body of Firebase notification, you can even use a JSON string with multiple parameters inside of that.

Comment: Do You mean POST to firebase from app?

Comment: No, I mean when you send the notification from Firebase you can put the link that you want to open in a web view in the body of your notification

Comment: Send notification than read on the MyFirebaseInstanceService?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I don't understand, but this service is bad work for me. I have start its from activity, add to manifest. But 1 from 10 push i can read on the MessageReceive. So thank you for your help.